# Convert Pandas dataframe into required python dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe in the format given below, The time column will be dynamic and it will be between 00:00 to 23:00 in 30 minute interval

```
name        start_time      end_time        10:00:00    10:30:00
student1    1598758200000   1598761800000   False       False
student2    1598779800000   1598790600000   False       False
student3    1598765400000   1598770800000   False       True
student4    1598248800000   1598252400000   False       True
student5    1598293800000   1598297400000   False       False
```

I need to convert this dataframe into a python dictionary like below

**Output:**

```
{
    "10:00:00":[
        "student1",
        "student2",
        "student3",
        "student4",
        "student5"
    ],
    "10:30:00":[
        "student1",
        "student2",
        "student5"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

May not be the most efficient but here's one way to do it (let's call your dataframe my_df):

```
my_dict = dict([(k,[x for i,x in enumerate(my_df['name']) if not my_df[k][i]]) for k in my_df.columns if k not in ['name', 'start_time', 'end_time']])
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this code is looks easier:

```
excluded_columns = {"name", "start_time", "end_time"}
result = {}
for column in set(df.columns) - excluded_columns:
    temp_lst = df['name'][df[column] == False].to_list()
    if temp_lst:
        result[column] = temp_lst
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution, use [`DataFrame.filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html#pandas-dataframe-filter) to select the column(s) with timestamp & use [`DataFrame.stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html#pandas-dataframe-stack) + [`DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html#pandas-dataframe-groupby) to get into desired outcome.

```
In [22]: stack_ = df.set_index('name').filter(regex=r"^\d{2}:\d{2}").stack()

In [23]: stack_                                                                                      
Out[23]: 
name              
student1  10:00:00    False
          10:30:00    False
student2  10:00:00    False
          10:30:00    False
student3  10:00:00    False
          10:30:00     True
student4  10:00:00    False
          10:30:00     True
student5  10:00:00    False
          10:30:00    False
dtype: bool

In [24]: stack_ = stack_[~stack_].reset_index()

In [25]: stack_                                                                                                                                                   
Out[25]: 
       name   level_1      0
0  student1  10:00:00  False
1  student1  10:30:00  False
2  student2  10:00:00  False
3  student2  10:30:00  False
4  student3  10:00:00  False
5  student4  10:00:00  False
6  student5  10:00:00  False
7  student5  10:30:00  False

In [26]: stack_.groupby('level_1')['name'].apply(list).to_dict()
Out[26]: 
{'10:00:00': ['student1', 'student2', 'student3', 'student4', 'student5'],
 '10:30:00': ['student1', 'student2', 'student5']}
```

Answer (score 1):

use `pivot_table`+`unstack`+`groupby`

try this,

```
temp = df.pivot_table(index='name', values=["10:00:00", "10:30:00"])
temp = temp.unstack().reset_index()
temp=temp[~temp[0]]
temp.groupby('level_0')['name'].apply(list).to_dict()
```

O/P:

```
 {'10:00:00': ['student1', 'student2', 'student3', 'student4', 'student5'],
 '10:30:00': ['student1', 'student2', 'student5']}
```